# Multiple loops using next_posts_link & previous_posts_link

Tags: loop, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have more than one loop in the same page and they are working perfectly,
but the problem comes up when I try to use `next_posts_link` & `previous_posts_link` for a specific `div`.

Example:

```
<div id="example1"><div id="next1"><?php next_posts_link('<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/next.jpg" />'); ?></div>
<div id="previous1"><?php previous_posts_link('<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/previous.jpg" />'); ?></div></div>
```

When I click on next or previous for a specific `div`, why do all the other divs that contain `next_posts_link` & `previous_posts_link` get updated also?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `wp_reset_query();` after each loop?

Please provide complete code for your template then we may can help.